# Computing actual position of an SVG Path object

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

This is WPF-based desktop project. Part of the project reads an SVG file containing several `path` elements. I'm using [Svg](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG) package for loading and parsing svg content.

At the ViewModel layer, I have my Model class named `Path`. Once SVG elements are loaded and parsed, I create `Path` objects for each `path` element and hydrate its props (e.g. path data, stroke, fill etc.). The ViewModel exposes a collection property that contains all these Path models.

At View layer, I have an `ItemsControl` that uses a `Canvas` as its panel and an `ItemTemplate` containing a WPF `Path` object, whose `PathData` is bound to model's path data, `Fill` is bound to model's Fill prop and so on.

So far so good. I can read the SVG, create my models and they display in the view, but...

Since SVG paths do not have location or size props, I need to compute those to place my WPF `Path` objects at correct positions. Fortunately, Svg library provides `SvgPath.Bounds` property that returns bounding box of an SVG Path. I use this to hydrate `Location` and `Size` properties of my models. However, this results in a strangely scaled and repositioned output. Here is an example of actual SVG vs. WPF render:

[image: Actual SVG]

[image: Rendered Output]

I've tried re-scaling the paths using `GetFlattenedPathGeometry` too, but it doesn't get show exactly like it should.

What do I need to fix?

### Edit

Here is the problem SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   viewBox="0 0 36 36"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg24"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs28" />
  <path
     fill="#4289c1"
     d="M 281.73267,37.528917 V 248.00919 c 0,0 0,31.18229 -31.18227,31.18229 H 32.274555 c -31.1822696,0 -31.1822696,-31.18229 -31.1822696,-31.18229 v -38.97782 c 0,0 194.8891546,-15.59113 280.6403846,-171.502453 z"
     id="path2"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#1c6399"
     d="m 249.3343,179.74342 c 0,0 19.99561,-12.74575 17.60238,-17.83625 -2.40883,-5.09828 -91.81619,7.71762 -136.64067,23.02811 -67.252365,22.97354 -102.464935,58.63824 -97.647265,68.81925 4.80986,10.18101 59.2619,15.22475 126.506445,-7.74099 44.8401,-15.31049 119.80225,-58.65385 117.40123,-63.74433 -2.40884,-5.09053 -27.22212,-2.52579 -27.22212,-2.52579 z"
     id="path4"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#a6d388"
     d="m 246.44994,175.87685 c 0,0 20.65824,-12.62103 18.31177,-17.85965 -2.36206,-5.24642 -93.87421,6.09614 -139.92262,20.85312 -69.099895,22.14723 -105.731245,57.8743 -101.014925,68.35931 4.71631,10.48505 60.20516,16.69032 129.289465,-5.44908 46.07177,-14.757 123.42718,-57.55467 121.0807,-62.79329 -2.36203,-5.24642 -27.74439,-3.11041 -27.74439,-3.11041 z"
     id="path6"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#f5f8fa"
     d="m 246.44994,175.87685 c 0,0 19.54347,-11.95842 18.38192,-17.42311 L 30.372425,232.24658 c -5.6284,6.52489 -7.94367,11.87264 -6.54826,14.98305 1.21609,2.71289 5.88565,5.12171 13.25244,6.84452 L 274.02285,179.50176 c 0.0249,-0.15589 0.226,-0.39756 0.17145,-0.51453 -2.36203,-5.24642 -27.74439,-3.11041 -27.74439,-3.11041 z"
     id="path8"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#af7e57"
     d="m 217.45822,93.914237 c -4.59159,-1.83194 -10.50841,-2.15157 -16.40186,-3.00906 -9.33911,-1.364229 -22.23297,-5.963629 -27.51057,-8.465999 -6.43134,-3.85879 -20.08917,-12.948431 -23.48023,-15.185771 -3.39109,-2.23731 -7.92808,-5.33994 -13.52531,-6.33779 h -1.21612 c 3.00131,4.2252 4.74751,9.03506 5.83108,22.147201 0,0 25.87349,12.948419 28.02507,13.665629 8.77001,2.92335 24.80548,2.85317 33.86395,3.991333 4.69291,0.59247 7.95925,-0.10902 11.68555,-0.36637 5.62839,-0.381993 10.75788,-0.428743 11.08528,-2.892143 0.38977,-2.861 -4.63835,-2.06583 -8.35684,-3.54701 z M 115.67152,6.3232673 c -12.41834,-4.88782 -31.782535,1.4188 -34.027655,15.9263397 -2.23734,14.40621 1.86315,37.00556 14.52313,35.64133 13.268065,-1.43439 26.879135,-4.31876 32.258055,-17.98437 5.37896,-13.65783 -0.33517,-28.69548 -12.75353,-33.5832997 z"
     id="path10"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#af7e57"
     d="m 124.90147,43.430147 c 18.07013,-21.22731 -25.460335,-19.16147 -25.460335,-19.16147 -8.23989,0.2962 -2.56474,14.02421 -6.44693,21.52354 -2.65829,5.18405 8.536165,7.93588 8.536165,7.93588 0,0 5.13726,-0.0781 5.41013,6.15852 v 0.0547 c 0.0624,1.59029 -0.10136,3.46903 -0.84193,5.99479 -3.68732,12.480681 13.07315,20.128151 16.75265,7.624071 1.45779,-4.950201 0.88872,-9.300131 0.15588,-13.314841 l -0.0701,-0.35859 c -1.12255,-5.97141 -2.51018,-11.21003 1.9645,-16.45646 z m -38.065745,20.6193 c -12.98741,7.740991 -26.25546,23.768661 -31.02637,30.51182 -2.8064,2.20616 -5.34776,4.78649 -6.9926,5.737553 -3.03249,1.73841 -16.79167,11.16325 -25.99044,15.63013 -2.75962,1.29405 -11.36593,3.41445 -15.5287596,6.08832 -3.36769,2.16716 -6.58724005,2.04244 -5.66738,4.77088 0.79514,2.35428 3.96015,1.68386 9.5651496,1.02902 5.60503,-0.65483 15.03766,-2.25292 18.12471,-4.4123 6.23644,-4.13944 26.09176,-9.01167 35.83621,-15.8328 1.72283,-1.20831 18.59243,-16.861793 21.67948,-21.367642 4.23299,-11.81027 2.19833,-19.925441 0,-22.154981 z"
     id="path12"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#60352a"
     d="M 129.85944,11.335807 C 121.58834,1.6537373 110.21461,-2.3609827 90.733505,5.1695173 73.715785,11.748967 79.188265,25.274277 83.156215,22.959007 c 14.56989,-8.49718 22.599335,4.00691 28.820215,17.68814 4.07707,8.97269 12.16107,11.70894 12.16107,11.70894 0,0 2.62712,1.02903 7.10954,-7.80336 4.48246,-8.83239 6.82893,-23.60498 -1.3876,-33.21692 z"
     id="path14"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557;fill:#0000ff" />
  <path
     fill="#af7e57"
     d="m 127.85599,220.19464 c -2.94672,-0.77955 -5.22303,-3.36769 -6.29101,-6.11953 -0.45993,-1.18494 -2.84538,-7.80336 -2.84538,-7.80336 h -14.18015 c 0.33524,1.66825 -0.28842,5.42572 -1.04461,9.3313 -0.48334,2.51018 -0.88869,6.95363 -0.10135,8.52054 0.78734,1.56692 6.36897,5.76874 10.14202,6.54048 9.64312,1.98787 19.41876,-2.6661 20.61146,-4.0303 1.73061,-1.98787 -3.33649,-5.6596 -6.29101,-6.43913 z m 58.54468,-25.11733 c -2.60372,-0.50675 -4.7319,-2.61931 -5.81548,-4.94239 -0.46772,-1.00563 -1.71501,-5.07492 -1.71501,-5.07492 l -12.54307,1.71504 c 0.38978,1.42658 -0.21036,3.25074 -0.0624,6.18187 0.1326,2.61153 -0.45215,5.83108 0.32746,7.14855 0.77174,1.31745 4.68511,4.45126 8.00604,4.90341 8.48156,1.15372 16.69028,-3.45345 17.64916,-4.70853 1.37201,-1.83195 -3.24297,-4.71632 -5.84669,-5.22303 z"
     id="path16"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#60352a"
     d="m 127.28692,15.849457 c 6.82113,-10.2277897 21.62489,-11.2100297 28.35247,-3.65614 6.72757,7.55392 9.23775,17.54002 18.22602,17.54002 2.86878,0 4.30315,2.68169 -1.65265,5.36337 -5.95583,2.68166 -30.31697,8.03721 -39.57028,-9.26114 -4.13947,-5.1139 -5.35556,-9.98611 -5.35556,-9.98611 z"
     id="path18"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557;fill:#ff0000" />
  <path
     fill="#292f33"
     d="m 178.65188,171.93228 c 0.17941,-5.50367 3.2118,-17.09567 2.06583,-22.0147 -1.78518,-7.64743 -11.69336,-15.95751 -20.86873,-22.98131 -9.17538,-7.02381 -18.51445,-11.21003 -18.51445,-11.21003 -2.35428,-14.78038 1.88651,-22.575943 1.83194,-28.968302 -0.0468,-5.3322 -3.37547,-20.642691 -7.84234,-25.842321 h -12.20004 c 0,0 1.91769,7.8969 -5.04374,8.66868 -6.97702,0.77175 -11.28019,-8.66868 -11.28019,-8.66868 l -13.626635,1.30185 c -2.16718,0.33524 -4.27977,0.97447 -6.3378,1.83976 2.93113,4.98137 1.79297,17.812891 0,22.147201 6.41573,9.261149 11.97398,23.410112 8.93371,40.973492 -2.69727,15.60673 3.68729,30.31698 3.68729,33.70804 0,0 -3.92117,13.63443 -1.55911,22.59154 3.141625,11.91943 5.987005,22.48243 6.314435,26.68422 11.00732,0 15.44299,-3.04026 15.44299,-3.04026 0,0 -2.16715,-4.97356 -1.28625,-12.29362 0.53788,-4.45904 2.73623,-11.34254 2.73623,-17.96097 0,-6.61844 -0.17152,-11.38933 0.81076,-14.12557 0.98223,-2.73623 4.05367,-12.28579 6.32999,-21.0792 4.16283,2.27629 11.63878,6.1741 16.24596,7.43698 6.61844,1.80855 11.64657,4.63835 13.39278,6.15848 1.7462,1.52013 2.93112,2.61153 2.93112,2.61153 0,0 -0.54566,4.87221 -0.0781,12.34035 0.42875,6.83674 4.13166,12.09094 4.958,20.2373 6.96143,-1.03681 13.55648,-4.11605 13.55648,-4.11605 0,0 -0.74838,-9.877 -0.60026,-14.39841 z"
     id="path20"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
  <path
     fill="#67757f"
     d="m 97.562405,65.546187 7.047205,-0.67042 c 0,0 9.37028,10.703311 16.33951,9.931561 6.96924,-0.77178 6.55607,-10.555201 6.55607,-10.555201 h 9.89258 c -0.66264,-1.30966 -1.34865,-2.48678 -2.07364,-3.33651 h -12.20004 c 0,0 1.91769,7.8969 -5.04374,8.66868 -6.97702,0.77175 -11.28019,-8.66868 -11.28019,-8.66868 l -13.626635,1.30185 c -2.16718,0.33524 -4.27977,0.97447 -6.3378,1.83976 0.60025,1.02122 0.99783,2.42443 1.28625,3.96796 2.69727,-0.91989 7.58509,-2.19836 9.44043,-2.479 z M 165.12658,173.54596 c -0.46772,-7.46815 0.0781,-12.34038 0.0781,-12.34038 0,0 -1.17714,-1.09918 -2.93112,-2.61153 -0.5301,-0.45993 -1.44998,-1.06017 -2.54135,-1.69942 l 1.08356,0.98224 c 0,0 -0.54566,4.87223 -0.0781,12.34038 0.42875,6.83671 4.13166,12.09092 4.958,20.2373 1.23168,-0.18708 2.43999,-0.44437 3.61714,-0.725 -1.36424,-5.94801 -3.83543,-10.57859 -4.18623,-16.18359 z m -62.84005,13.26025 c -2.362065,-8.95711 1.55911,-22.59155 1.55911,-22.59155 0,-3.39105 -6.220865,-21.75742 -3.52358,-37.36413 31.18226,-0.16379 41.00466,-11.12429 41.00466,-11.12429 0,0 -21.19613,9.82242 -40.54474,4.15505 -0.57684,-13.93848 -6.142895,-28.539573 -13.307025,-35.695902 -0.19481,0.77955 -0.41318,1.46556 -0.63923,2.01126 6.41573,9.261119 11.97398,23.410082 8.93371,40.973502 -2.69727,15.60672 3.68729,30.31694 3.68729,33.70802 0,0 -3.92117,13.63444 -1.55911,22.59155 3.141625,11.91941 5.987005,22.48241 6.314435,26.68422 1.3876,0 2.66607,-0.0468 3.85099,-0.13259 -1.00563,-5.23862 -3.28192,-13.76697 -5.77651,-23.21521 z"
     id="path22"
     style="stroke-width:7.79557" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Some parts are scaled differently (e.g. the red part has a bigger proportion in the output). Are there `transform` attributes in the SVG?

Comment: @qrsngky: No. There is no transform attribute in the input SVG.

Comment: @JonasH: SVG file is selected by the user at runtime.

Comment: Isn't it more usual for the geometry of each path to define their own location?  If you use inkscape to open this problem SVG file then save as xaml, what do you get?

Comment: @Andy: Save as XAML in Inkscape produces one WPF `Path` for each `path` element. But these path elements do not have any extra attributes for location or size. They look like this: `<Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path18" Fill="#FF60352A" StrokeThickness="7.79557"><Path.Data><PathGeometry Figures="<ENTIRE PATH DATA>" FillRule="NonZero"/></Path.Data></Path>`. Their path data is identical to the path data of `path` elements.

Comment: If you take that xaml and stick it in a scratch Wpf window, what's it look like?  You should supply at least a link to an example bad SVG. At the moment I think your question is likely to be closed. There's insufficient info for anyone to reproduce your issue so there can be no definitive answer, only guesses.

Comment: @Andy: Sure. Added entire SVG in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out finally.

`Path.Bounds` property in SVG library does not return correct bounds of the Path object. This has been [reported on project website](https://github.com/svg-net/SVG/issues/922). Here is what they have to say:

> Bounds does not return accurate values for users. (If anything, it's used for rendering.)

They did not specify the right way of getting actual Path bounds. In my case though, I have started using WPF to calculate the real bounds, which can be done using:

`Geometry.Parse(pathData).Bounds.Size`

My application now displays it exactly like the original SVG.